# Piping events from ScrollContainer

Tags: javascript, dom-events, pipe, famo.us

I'm trying to pipe mouse clicks from `ScrollContainer` encapsulated in a view, but somehow nothing's happening. I've just started playing with Famo.us so maybe I'm missing something obvious here. I can pipe directly from surfaces contained within `ScrollContainer` but I'm not sure if that's the way to do it. Any ideas ?

Link to runnable jsFiddle demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/nqxz596f/

And the code itself :

```
define('main', function (require, exports, module) {
    var Engine          = require('famous/core/Engine');
    var Surface         = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Transform       = require('famous/core/Transform');
    var View            = require('famous/core/View');
    var Scrollview      = require('famous/views/ScrollContainer');

    var context = Engine.createContext();
    var mainview = new View({
        size: [500, 500]
    });
    var scrollview = new Scrollview({
        scrollview: {direction:0, size: [undefined, 300]}
    });
    var surfaces = [];

    scrollview.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        var surface = new Surface({
             content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
             size: [undefined, 200],
             properties: {
                 backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
                 lineHeight: "200px",
                 textAlign: "center"
             }
        });

        surface.pipe(scrollview);
        surfaces.push(surface);
    }
    
    mainview._eventInput.on('click', function(){
        console.log('click');
    });
    
    scrollview.pipe(mainview);
    mainview.add(scrollview);

    context.add(mainview);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, the ScrollContainer does not have it's own EventHandlers. It uses the [event handlers from the ScrollView that it contains](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/master/views/ScrollContainer.js#L39-L40) (`scrollcontainer.scrollview`). The ScrollContainer has a ContainerSurface that subscribes from the events of the `scrollcontainer.scrollview` and is the DOM element to hide the overflow of the scrollview.

[The below code in a new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parmaqzL/) shows the correct way to setup the ContainerSurface.  You do not need the `mainview` to pipe your events.

You have a couple options:

- Pipe the surface events to the scrollview event output (as below) and listen on the scrollview for the events
- or Pipe the surface events to the container `surface.pipe(scrollcontainer.container);` and listen to the events from the container `scrollcontainer.container.on('click', ...`

**Corrected Code:**

```
define('main', function (require, exports, module) {
    var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
    var View = require('famous/core/View');
    var ScrollContainer = require('famous/views/ScrollContainer');
    var Scrollview = require('famous/views/Scrollview');
    var Utility = require('famous/utilities/Utility');

    var context = Engine.createContext();

    var scrollcontainer = new ScrollContainer({

        scrollview: {
            direction: Utility.Direction.Y
        }
    });
    scrollcontainer.container.setSize([500, 500]);

    var surfaces = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        var surface = new Surface({
            content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
            size: [undefined, 200],
            properties: {
                backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
                lineHeight: "200px",
                textAlign: "center"
            }
        });

        surface.pipe(scrollcontainer.scrollview._eventOutput);
        surfaces.push(surface);
    }

    scrollcontainer.scrollview.on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('click ' + e.target.innerText);
    });

    scrollcontainer.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

    context.add(scrollcontainer);
});
```

**Alternative Option:**

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        var surface = new Surface({
            content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
            size: [undefined, 200],
            properties: {
                backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
                lineHeight: "200px",
                textAlign: "center"
            }
        });

        surface.pipe(scrollcontainer.container);
        surfaces.push(surface);
    }

    scrollcontainer.container.on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('click ' + e.target.innerText);
    });
```

**[jsFiddle to show event pipe to a View](http://jsfiddle.net/bq3yqywb/)**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    var surface = new Surface({
        content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
        size: [undefined, 200],
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
            lineHeight: "200px",
            textAlign: "center"
        }
    });

    surface.pipe(scrollcontainer.container);
    surfaces.push(surface);
}

var mainview = new View({size: [500, 500]});

mainview.on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('click ' + e.target.innerText);
});

scrollcontainer.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

scrollcontainer.container.pipe(mainview._eventOutput);

context.add(scrollcontainer).add(mainview);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Are you in some way involved into this project or just hacking with it ?

Comment: Not an employee of Famo.us. I have been hacking on it for some time.  I am active most days on irc (freenode) #famous.  There are a few of us that contribute there as well as here.